# Can't get user input using Rust Enhanced package on Sublime Text 3

Tags: rust, sublimetext3

I've installed Rust Enhanced package on Sublime Text 3 and everything works just fine until I try to get user input!.

As you can see in the next picture when I print Hello World! and press enter nothing happens! which means user input is not being processed?

[image: Rust Enhanced package in Sublime 3]

I'm expecting Rust to print (Hello World!) again on the user screen.

So is there a solution?.

If there's not can you suggest any alternatives?.

Comment: It looks like you aren't running the code you think you're running. There is no `"Hello world!"` in the code in the screenshot

Comment: @user25064 Thats because (Hello World) is just an example of a user input .. just look at the bottom of the screenshot

Comment: interesting, does it work on command line? the compiled result is in the target folder

Comment: Yes it does work on command line. I believe the issue is that these kind of packages does not support user input processing or something like that. And i found someone who had the exact same problem but with Python.

Comment: My guess would be that Sublimetext communicates with child processes through pipes and that rust (and python) change their buffering behaviour when `stdin` is a pipe rather than a tty. Can you try to type a lot of extra random data after you type `return`?

Comment: What you type into the output panel doesn't get sent to the program you're running because Sublime doesn't connect it to the standard input of the thing you're running. If you want to run a program that's interactive, you need to run it externally.

Answer (score 2):

1 . Preferences >Package Control: Install Package.

2 . install package Terminus.

3 .  Tools > Build Systems > New Build System

It should have opened a new file untitled.sublime-build, erase all its content and paste :

```
{
"selector": "source.rust",
"target": "terminus_exec",
"cancel": "terminus_cancel_build",
"shell_cmd": "cargo build",
"file_regex": "^(.*?):([0-9]+):([0-9]+):\\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+\\s(.*)$",

"variants": [
    {
        "name": "Cargo run",
        "shell_cmd": "cargo run",
    },
    {
        "name": "Cargo check",
        "shell_cmd": "cargo check",
    },
    {
        "name": "Rustc build & run",
        "shell_cmd": "rustc \"$file\" && \"./$file_base_name\"",
    },
    {
        "name": "Rustc build",
        "shell_cmd": "rustc \"$file\"",
    },
    {
        "name": "Rustc run",
        "shell_cmd": "./$file_base_name",
        "windows":
        {
            "cmd": ["$file_base_name.exe"]
        }, 
    },
]
```

}

5 . Save this file under any name like : RustTerminus.sublime-build.

6 . Tools > Build Systems, and select the build system RustTerminus.

7 . Then with ctrl+shift+B choose your variant build.

8 . it should open a console within Sublime Text 3 where the result of your code is displayed, you can use input with this console !